# meaning of `ASTSQLSchemaStatement(JJTSQLSCHEMASTATEMENT)` and `jjtree.openNodeScope`

Tags: javacc

these lines appears in the generated file of .jj file

```
ASTSQLSchemaStatement jjtn000 = new ASTSQLSchemaStatement(JJTSQLSCHEMASTATEMENT);
boolean jjtc000 = true;
jjtree.openNodeScope(jjtn000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together they create a new node and open its scope.  (And declare a boolean var.)  The node's scope will remain open until it is closed or abandoned.  While it is open, it may acquire children. When it is closed it will be pushed on a stack and may become the child of some other open node.  See https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html for more details.

Comment: but the link tell me that: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Comment: My mistake.  I've corrected the URL. It's  https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ASTSQLSchemaStatement jjtn000 = new ASTSQLSchemaStatement(JJTSQLSCHEMASTATEMENT);
```

This will create an instance of an object of type ASTSQLSchemaStatement.

```
boolean jjtc000 = true;
```

This will create a primitive boolean with the value true.

```
jjtree.openNodeScope(jjtn000);
```

This is a method call on a variable called `jjtree` (I don't know what type this is), sending the instance of `ASTSQLSchemaStatement` we created earlier.